# Delete a record in Data grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have added a data grid view in Asp page, data is retrieved from the sqlserver2005 and its showing in data grid view, even i have made the auto-generate-delete as TRUE in the properties but when i run the page and click on delete button its showing error.

plz give me some solution

Thanks,
Churchill

Comment: can u show us the error pls ?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?

Comment: delete command is not specified plz tell me the delete command how to delete record in data grid view

Comment: How did you bind the grid? By object data source or through datatable

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

[Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Data with the SqlDataSource](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

need to [generated delete statement when creating data source](http://sfvt.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/asp-net-tutorial-gridview-delete-row-with-button/).